# How can I change column comments in existing Hive table without including new column name and type?

Tags: hive

I want to change the column comments on an existing hive table using hive 0.13. This works:

create table test (mycolumn int);
alter table test change mycolumn mycolumn int comment 'hello';

But I can't find a way to do this without repeating the name of the column and the type, both of which are irrelevant to the change. For example:

alter table test change mycolumn comment 'hello'; leads to an error.

If this was for one column it would not be a big deal but I want to do this for large numbers of columns in tables that were not commented. I know this could be done with a script that simply copies the column name and its type but would be nice to know if there were something simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using ALTER command.

```
CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT COMMENT 'id comment',
name STRING comment 'name comment');

-- change column comment as below.
ALTER TABLE my_table CHANGE id id INT COMMENT 'another comment';
-- see changed column
DESC EXTENDED my_table;
```

Answer (score 5):

```sql
ALTER TABLE test_change CHANGE a1 a1 INT COMMENT 'this is column a1';
```

Answer (score 0):

Directly its not supported to edit column property for **comment** the other way around is

```sql
alter table dev.travel change  num2  clm_num1  int comment 'a new column added';
```

Now I want to change above one lets do ;

```sql
alter table dev.tkt change  clm_num1 num2 int comment 'a new column added';
alter table dev.tkt change  num2 clm_num1  int  comment 'a new column added with new comment';
```

Comment: Try this guys now